# Firebase doesn't insert any data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to insert data in Realtime database on Firebase.

I'm trying to create a tree for users like this:

```
buscacerto-inc
 |___users
       |___id
       |   |____Nome
       |   |____cpf
       |   |____email
       |
       |___id
           |____Nome
           |____cpf
           |____email
```

But when I execute the code to insert data, the code seems to work correctly (without any errors or exceptions) but do not insert anything into Firebase.

My app is connected and sync.

My code is:

```
try{
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference refer = database.getReference("buscacerto-inc/users");
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(email, senha); //My class Usuario
        refer.push().setValue(usuario.pegaEmail(), usuario.pegaSenha());
        Toast.makeText(actCadastro.this, "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(actCadastro.this, "Erro: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2sSx.png)

This is my firebase's RealTime Database

Comment: Please attach error log. That's the only way to identify your mistakes.

Comment: If you check the logcat output of your app, is there anything relevant at the moment the `setValue` call runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
My app, in firebase, had too many "Server Key" on the cloud Messaging tab, in the database configurations.

I just delete all the "Server key" and, when I refreshed the browser, the Firebase has created a new "Server key" and the app can get insert new users.